# Abbreviating constructor names in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, abbreviation

I have two modules.  One defines a variant type:

```
module A = struct
  type foo = Bar of material | Baz | Boo

  (* other stuff *)
end
```

and I would like to be able to use `foo`'s variants both as constructors and as left-hand-sides in another module

```
module B = struct
  type foo = A.foo  (* I can abbreviate A.foo by assigning it a local alias *)

  let f (x : foo) = match x with
    | Bar m       -> Bar (g m)  (* Any way to abbreviate Bar and friends? *)
    | Baz   | Boo -> x
end
```

but per ["referring to named objects"](http://askra.de/software/ocaml-doc/3.12/full-grammar.html#constr) I have to prefix the variant names with a *module-path*:

```
  let f (x : foo) = match x with
    | A.Bar m         -> A.Bar (g m)
    | A.Baz   | A.Boo -> x
```

Is there any way to skip avoid using the module path short of `open`ing and pulling in all the other stuff from `A`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can open A locally:

```
let f (x : foo) = A.(match x with
  | Bar m       -> Bar (g m)
  | Baz   | Boo -> x)
```

or

```
let f (x : foo) =
  let open A in
  match x with
  | Bar m       -> Bar (g m)
  | Baz   | Boo -> x)
```

You can define `Bar` in a submodule so that less things are exposed:

```
module A = struct
  module BasicDataAndOps = struct
    type foo = Bar of material | Baz | Boo
  end
  open BasicDataAndOps
  (* other stuff *)
end

module B = struct
  open A.BasicDataAndOps
  ...
```

For use outside of patterns, you can define a "smart constructor" in B:

```
let bar m = A.Bar m
```

ETA: I forgot about the possibility to restate type definition, described in Ashish Argwal's answer: `type foo = A.foo = Bar of material | Baz | Boo`. Given that you already have type abbreviation in your example, this is the best answer.

There is some work on [type-based label disambiguation](http://gallium.inria.fr/~scherer/gagallium/resolving-field-names/) which could be helpful, but it may not get accepted into the language.

Comment: If by "behind the scenes" work you are referring to the [proposal of type-based label disambiguation](http://gallium.inria.fr/~scherer/gagallium/resolving-field-names/), then (1) it may not be accepted in the end and (2) it should work for (non-polymorphic) variant constructors just as well as for record labels.

Comment: the `open in` syntax is available in OCaml from ver 3.12 upward.

Comment: Thanks GaSche, yes I was referring to that proposal. I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers lukstafi gave, you can also re-state the constructors when defining `B.foo`.

```
module A = struct
  type foo = Bar | Baz
end

module B = struct
  type foo = A.foo = Bar | Baz

let f (x : foo) = match x with
  | Bar -> "bar"
  | Baz -> "baz"

end
```

Comment: Is this the *type-equation* bit in [3.2](http://askra.de/software/ocaml-doc/3.12/manual016.html#toc54)?